# How to find number of occurrence of highest element in an Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function findMaxOccurence(ar){    
        ar.sort().reverse() // Reverses a sorted array Max to min 
        count = 0;
        for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
            ++count
            if(i == ar.length - 1){//break out when last element reached
                break
            }
            if(ar[i+1] != ar[i]){
                break
            }
        }
    return count
}
```

How to find number of occurrence of highest element in an Javascript Array ?

Comment: And what is the issue with available code?

Comment: This doesnt works perfectly !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method in order to write a more easy solution.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

```js
let dataset = [2,8,4,8,6,4,7,8];
let max= Math.max(...dataset);
var count = dataset.reduce(function(counter, value) {
    return counter + (value === max);
}, 0);
console.log(count);
```

Also, you can use `filter` method by passing a **callback** function.

```
let count = dataset.filter(x => x === max).length;
```

Comment: nice solution!!

Comment: what's the meaning of the 3 dots?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: You can also use `dataset.filter(x => x === max).length`

Comment: this solution has **O(nlogn) + O(n)**.

Answer (score 2):

Find the below two methods:

```
function findMaxOccurence(ar){    
    ar.sort().reverse(); // Reverses a sorted array Max to min
    var count = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++){
        if(ar[i] == ar[0])
            count++;
    }
    return count
}

function findMaxOccurence(ar){    
    ar.sort().reverse(); // Reverses a sorted array Max to min
    var count = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i < ar.length; i++){
        if(ar[i] != ar[0])
            break;
        count++;
    }
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in a single loop with an object as temporary result set.

```js
function findMaxOccurence(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(r, a) {
        if (!r || a > r.value) {
            return { value: a, count: 1 };
        }
        if (r.value === a) {
            r.count++;
        }
        return r;
    }, undefined).count;
}

console.log(findMaxOccurence([1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both these solutions provided below, just remember that the filter solution is a bit faster ^^

```js
//Code

let dataset = [2,8,4,8,6,4,7,8];

let t0 = performance.now();
countWithReduce(dataset);
let t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to countWithReduce took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

t0 = performance.now();
countWithFilter(dataset);
t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to countWithFilter took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")


//Functions

function countWithReduce(arr){
    let max= Math.max(...arr);
    let count = arr.reduce(function(counter, value) {
        return counter + (value === max);
    }, 0);
    console.log(count);
}

function countWithFilter(arr){
    let max= Math.max(...arr);
    let count = arr.filter(x => x === max).length;
    console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution for testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMaxOccurence(ar){
ar.sort((a, b) => b - a);
let count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
if(ar[i] === ar[0]){
count++;
}
}
return count;
}
```

So, basically what I did with this solution is use the `sort((a, b) => a - b)` method.

This sorts the array in descending order, which is the most effective in case you're dealing with bigger numbers (for example 102, 113, etc.) for which the reverse method will not be effective.

Then create a count variable to keep track of the number of occurence of the maximum element in the array.

Then run a for loop and compare the elements in the index of ar[i] and add to the count, if that element is equal to ar[0], which will be the maximum element after rearranging the elements in descending order.

Comment: So, basically what I did with this solution is use the sort((a, b) => a - b) method to sort the array in descending order which is the most effective incase you're dealing with bigger numbers for example 102, 113, etc where the reverse method will not be effective. Then create a count variable to keep track of the number of occurence of  the maximum element in the array. Then run a for loop and compare the elements in the index of ar[i] and add to the count if that element is equal to ar[0] which will be the maximum element after rearranging the elements in descending order.